# Create python network graph from 3 dataframe columns unweighted using networkx and pyvis

Tags: python, networkx, pyviz

Im working to create a python network graph utilizing the 3 pandas dataframe string columns - unweighted (python networks and pyviz)

I would like to link (nodes) the projects to country, and projects to company.

my table/dataframe is as follow;

| Company | Project | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T-mobile | 5G upgrade | Germany |
| T-mobile | Network upgrade | Kuwait |

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear: What do you mean by _"link"_?

Comment: @Timus just a network chart between this three nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the DataFrame containing your data is `df` (and it has three columns, i.e. "Company", "Project" and "Country". This would be a possible solution:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    pd.DataFrame({
        'source': pd.concat((df['Project'], df['Project'])),
        'target': pd.concat((df['Company'], df['Country']))
    }),
)
```

Here are the nodes and edges of `G`:

```
>>> G.nodes
NodeView(('5G upgrade', 'T-mobile', 'Network upgrade', 'Germany', 'Kuwait'))
>>> G.edges
EdgeView([('5G upgrade', 'T-mobile'), ('5G upgrade', 'Germany'),
('T-mobile', 'Network upgrade'), ('Network upgrade', 'Kuwait')])
```